# Changing checkbox visibility

Tags: javascript, html

I would like the button on my web page to toggle the visibility of my two check-boxes.

How do I go about implementing such functionality?

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=javascript>
function validate(chk){
  if (chk.style.visibility == 'visible')
    chk.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  else
    chk.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form><span id=t style.visibility="visible" >
<input type=checkbox name=chk1>Please Check Me</span>
<input type=checkbox name=chk1>Please Check Me</span>
<p><input type=button value="check" onclick="return validate(t);">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to keep your JavaScript code and CSS out of your HTML.

```
<span id="t">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</span>
<button id="toggler">Toggle</button>
```

For the JavaScript code, we look up the two elements via their ID. We then attach some logic to the `onclick` method of the button itself. This logic checks the present value of the `display` style on the span element. If it's visible, we hide it. If it's hidden, we show it.

```
document.getElementById("toggler").onclick = function(){
   var s = document.getElementById("t");
   (s.style.display == "none") ? s.style.display = "" : s.style.display = "none";
};​
```

Online demo: http://jsbin.com/iyiki/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving any object to the function. A quick fix is:

```
return validate(document.getElementById('t'));
```

Also, this HTML is wrong. It should be:

```
<span id="t" style="visibility:visible" >
```